# loop hosts variable using ansible

Tags: ansible

I want to realize function like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<nums;i++){
  hosts[i].something();
}
```

- I aim to loop this play and hosts is vm[0], vm[1], vm[2]……
- Here's an example of a mistake:

```
---
- hosts: vm[{{i}}]
  with_sequence: start=0 end=10 format=i%d
  gather_facts: False
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - import_tasks: test.yaml
```

How can I modify it?

Many thanks, maskingtime

Comment: Do you mean  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-items

Comment: @kriss, thank you, I will try to find the answer at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

So I think that you might have a couple of issues here, for starters, when you call with_sequence, it iterates to a variable called 'item', the system won't know what to do with the i variable you placed in it.  The format line just performs additional transformation into the string that it is going to place into "item".  If you want to name it something other than 'item' you have to append the loop_control and loop_var subarguments onto the task.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

Which brings us to the next point, I don't think that you can apply a loop to a playbook like that, I am pretty sure that you can only do that to tasks.

But if you goal is just iterate through a particular group of hosts that starts with the term 'vm' you can do that through the inventory.  In your inventory file, make a group that will bundle up a series of hosts like this:

```
[test_servers]
vm[0:10]
```

And then reformat your play to look like this:

```
---
- hosts: test_servers
  gather_facts: False
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
  - import_tasks: test.yaml
```